# Is there a way to get last and first edit timestamp for given article in one query?

Tags: wikipedia-api

What I found is how to get last revisions for an article:

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=42&prop=revisions&rvlimit=1

...and the creation date, that is first revision:

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=42&prop=revisions&rvdir=newer&rvlimit=1

but is there a way to combine both requests into one query ?

Comment: I don't think there is a way of getting that using the API.

Answer (score 1):

It is sort of hack, and not using the API, but if you for an article appen `?action=info` you will get a link to the current revision and the first revision but you will have to parse it yourself. The revision numbers are last in the URLs of the links for "Date of page creation" and "Date of latest edit" respecively. Example:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/42?action=info